# Unwanted Delay Declaring Image in ImageView within IBAction

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, delay, ibaction

**EDIT:** Code altered after recommendation from @llario - no improvement in delay.

I am new to objective-C and am having some issue with an unwanted delay loading images in to an imageView. I have started a new project which only assigns an image within the IBAction so when the button is clicked the delay occurs for the image to load for the first time only. Once the images have been used once they work as i want them to - rapid! How can I remove this delay on the first load so that the images load quickly the first time too? It is possible that there will be 12 buttons on my page each with 5 images assigned, meaning 60 images.

Striped back h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FCV2ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIImageView *animalImage;
    int imageNumber;
}

- (IBAction)hippoButtonClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

Striped back m file:

```
#import "FCV2ViewController.h"

@interface FCV2ViewController ()

@end

@implementation FCV2ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    imageNumber = 0;
    animalImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, 300, 300)];
    [self.view addSubview:animalImage];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)hippoButtonClicked:(id)sender
{

    if (imageNumber == 0) {
        animalImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hippo-00"];
        imageNumber++;
    }
    else if (imageNumber == 1) {
        animalImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hippo-01"];
        imageNumber = 0;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: This IBAction work well? Because i think that in this way int imageNumber on click will be ever 0.. You declare at every click an int =0.. I know that this isn't the question

Comment: Well it works and it cycles through the images so I guess it isn't the issue unless you feel that it would be better placed somewhere else?

Comment: are you using storyboard? yes i think that the int should be declared in your .h and in viewDidLoad set imageNumber = 0, not in your IBAction

Comment: OK thanks, I have set the int in h and altered the m to set the int in viewDidLoad. However this has made no difference to the way the app runs or the issues I am having - thanks anyway.

Comment: you use the storyboard? because if you have connected the IBOutlet in storyboard in your viewController, you don't need to [self.view addSubview:animalImage]

Comment: Yes i use it for the buttons but i have not used it for the image view  that appears when the button is clicked. Should i? I didn't bother as there is no image to put in it to start with and it will show different images on every click. What are you thinking? | So to answer your question, i have not linked an IBOutlet which is why I have used [self.view addSubview:animalImage]

Comment: try to remove IBOutlet from imageView in your .h because if you dont connect this in sotryboard you don't need this

Comment: OK I removed the IBOutlet from the imageView in the h file and it has made no difference, the first time every images is loaded they take a second or so longer than they do after the first time. It is as if there is a delay of 1 second in place.

Comment: this happens in simulator or in real device?

Comment: The delay happens on both the simulator and on real device (ipad3).

Comment: Do you think that it could be anything to do with the image sizes? For the retina iPad the image is 1.6MB?

Comment: 1.6MB is big.. check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very strange problem. the last thing I can suggest is to load the UIImage in viewDidLoad.. but if you have more images this is very inconvenient. for example:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FCV2ViewController : UIViewController
{
 UIImageView *animalImage;
 int imageNumber;
 UIImage *hippo00;
 UIImage *hippo01;
}

- (IBAction)hippoButtonClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "FCV2ViewController.h"

@interface FCV2ViewController ()

@end

@implementation FCV2ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  imageNumber = 0;
  animalImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, 300, 300)];
  [self.view addSubview:animalImage];

  hippo00 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hippo-00.png"];
  hippo01 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hippo-01.png"];

 }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

- (IBAction)hippoButtonClicked:(id)sender
 {

  if (imageNumber == 0) {
     animalImage.image = hippo00;
     imageNumber++;
  }
  else if (imageNumber == 1) {
     animalImage.image = hippo01;
     imageNumber = 0;
  }
 }

@end
```

Comment: Hey, OK so this helps a great deal and has sped things up a lot. I have to say though the first load of each image is still not as quick as the load time after. Thanks for your help. Any ideas why it isn't as quick?